# Python : import csv ignoring single comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, csv

i have a csv file below which works fine:

```
Test Case ID,summary

TC-16610,“verify that user is able to u_pdate 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'”
TC-16609,“verify that user is able to u_pdate 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'”
```

But if i add single comma it fails to parse:

```
Test Case ID,summary
,
TC-16610,“verify that user is able to u_pdate 'active' attribute  'false ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'true'”
TC-16609,“verify that user is able to u_pdate 'active' attribute  'true ' on adding “new category records” using 'v3/definition/categories' PUT API on specifying the 'active' attribute 'false'”
```

i want to parse csv file even while having single comma in it. either it should skip and parse or validate to parse. can anyone help me with this.

My code... i am using this in django :

```
class CsvUpload(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField()

    def clean_csv_file(self):
        # Probably worth doing this check first anyway
        value = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        if not value.name.endswith('.csv'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid file type')

        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(value.file, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python')

            data.columns= data.columns.str.strip().str.lower()
            data=data.rename(columns = {'test case id':'Test Case ID'})

            def transform(df):
                my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9"''-_“” \n\.]', '', df)
                return my_new_string

            data['summary'] = data['summary'].apply(transform)
        
        except KeyError:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                    'CSV file must have "summary" column and "Issue Key" column')
       
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error while parsing CSV file=> %s', e)
            raise forms.ValidationError('Failed to parse the CSV file')

        return data
```

EDIT: after parsing the file it leads to an exception 'Failed to parse the CSV file'and if i remove the last exception it leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\myproject\elixirdev\test_suite_optimizer\admin.py", line 282, in process_csv
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 180, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 376, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 397, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\myproject\elixirdev\test_suite_optimizer\forms.py", line 78, in clean_csv_file
    data['summary'] = data['summary'].apply(transform)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4045, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\myproject\elixirdev\test_suite_optimizer\forms.py", line 74, in transform
    my_new_string = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9"''-_“” \n\.]', '', df)
  File "c:\users\ssuri\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

After using:

```
data = data.dropna()
```

it leads to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\myproject\elixirdev\test_suite_optimizer\admin.py", line 287, in process_csv
    data = handle_demo_ai(csv_data)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\myproject\elixirdev\test_suite_optimizer\ai\web_demo_test_suite_optimization.py", line 108, in handle_json_ai
    X = df_tcs.loc[X_row, "Summary_lemmatized"]
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 805, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 929, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1850, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 160, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3737, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\ssuri\Envs\elixir\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: simple test - just reading a file as provided in the question works just fine with pandas. so there is something else that's going on.e.g.  you expect more columns in the file (summary, issue key), not present in the sample. That is to say I am not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes, the first file works fine but in second file i have written only single comma in second row and it gives me an error.

Comment: no, the second file works just fine. what error do you get? Note that your all catching exception is shadowing real cause of the problem.

Comment: Then i dont know whats the issue in my case while parsing second file it leads to the exception "Failed to parse the CSV file".

Comment: remove the last except, so that you see what the real problem is. and post the traceback you get here.

Comment: After removing the last except it leads:  to TypeError at /admin/test_suite_optimizer/duplicatetestcase/upload_csv/
expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: edit your question to include the full traceback, not just the last line. as well as consider rephrase the question.

Comment: As a side note, the smart quotes used in the file are not members of `ISO-8859-1` encoding.  You should likely use `Windows-1252` instead.

Comment: There are a number of errors in the code.  Keep the `try/except` commented out until you debug them all.

Comment: @MarkTolonen okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you read the file with the comma, first row has `NAN` values.
You need to drop `NAN` values before you try to apply `transform()`
use

`data = data.dropna()`

Comment: i am still facing error. i have edited question with recent traceback calls.

Comment: this is error from copletely different part of your code, not present here: `data = handle_demo_ai(csv_data)` and then `X = df_tcs.loc[X_row, "Summary_lemmatized"]`. I suggest to start new question about it if not able to solve it